# ambiguous reference to bindTo

Tags: ios, swift3, rx-swift

in `Swift3` i've a problem :

```
@IBOutlet weak var connectButton: UIButton!
[...]
viewModel.connectButtonTitle.asObservable().bindTo(connectButton.rx_title).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

> Cannont compile -> Ambiguous reference to bindTo.

I don't understand why.

Declaration of `connectButtonTitle`:

```
let connectButtonTitle = Variable<String?>("")
[...]
driver.isConnected.asObservable()
        .map({(isConnected:Bool) -> String in
            let connected = (!isConnected) ? "connect" : "disconnect";
            return connected + "blabla"
    }).bindTo(connectButtonTitle).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Thx for your help !

Comment: Is `rx_title` your custom property?

Comment: Yes it is, i use it in other file nothing wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to set title of your `UIButton` in needed state:
`viewModel.connectButtonTitle.asObservable().bindTo(button.rx.title(for: .normal)).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)`